# Command block to give specific player (in a certain radius) a status effect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Vanilla Minecraft 1.18, is there a way to give a specific player a status effect if they step within X blocks of an area?  I need to give Mining Fatigue on a certain player when they enter my base.

After extensive searching I've looked at the command `/effect give`

```
/effect give playerName minecraft:absorption 5 5 true
```

and also `/testfor`, but that doesn't seem to work.

The effect should only happen when a certain player is within a certain radius of the command block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`/effect give @a[name=playerName,distance=..radius] minecraft:absorption 5 5 true`

Comment: This command will only give the effect to players with that name. You should've used 
 @a[distance=..raidus] instead.

Comment: The question was asking for the selector to target a specific player, not all players within a radius. I may have misunderstood the question, but I think this is a valid answer.

Comment: I apologize, you are correct. It was I who misread the question. ‍♂️

Comment: It was quite ambiguous.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!